# Собрать правильно данные в массив array

Tags: php, массивы, yml

Уважаемые программисты! Необходимо правильно данные сложить в array(), чтобы потом можно было удобно достать. Доставать буду по последнему параметру (id:111,222,333,444) - это конечные категории.
Должны получиться arr с ключами 111,222,333,444

Есть YML файл. $yml->shop->categories->category все категории которые вы видите внизу. Далее foreach.

```
<category id="1">Одежда</category>
<category id="2" parentId="1">Мужская одежда</category>
<category id="3" parentId="1">Женская одежда</category>

<category id="4" parentId="2">М. Куртки</category>
<category id="111" parentId="4">М. Куртки осень</category>
<category id="222" parentId="4">М. Курткит зима</category>

<category id="5" parentId="3">Ж. Куртки</category>
<category id="333" parentId="5">Ж. Куртки осень</category>
<category id="444" parentId="5">Ж. Куртки зима</category>

$fullcattree=array();
foreach ($yml->shop->categories->category as $item)
    {
        if (!isset($item['parentId'])){
            $fullcattree[(int)$item['id']] = $item;
        } else {
            $fullcattree[(int)$item['id']] = $fullcattree[(int)$item['parentId']]."/".$item;

        }
    }
```

После foreach, то что у меня получилось в $fullcattree=array();

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е тут все нормально (еще конечно хотелось бы, чтобы 1,2,3,4,5 не сохранялись а только последнии категории как ключ 111,222,333,444), если parentId идет с верху в низ, не нарушая нумерацию от 0 до 9999999999 <- такая схема работает

тут я убираю в САМЫЙ НИЗ **Одежда category id="1"** и возникает ошибка:
Undefined offset: 1 - Неопределенное смещение: 1
т.е не может найти $fullcattree[(int)$item['parentId']] - что делать????))))
Если можно подробнее а то я ВАЛЕНОК) если еще и с рекурсией!

```
<category id="2" parentId="1">Мужская одежда</category>
<category id="3" parentId="1">Женская одежда</category>

<category id="4" parentId="2">М. Куртки</category>
<category id="111" parentId="4">М. Куртки осень</category>
<category id="222" parentId="4">М. Курткит зима</category>

<category id="5" parentId="3">Ж. Куртки</category>
<category id="333" parentId="5">Ж. Куртки осень</category>
<category id="444" parentId="5">Ж. Куртки зима</category>  
<category id="1">Одежда</category>
```

Comment: Какие id он не смог найти?

Comment: @ArchDemon  если я убираю Одежа id=1 с самого верха в самый низ, то Undefined offset: 1, Неопределенное смещение: 1

Comment: Кто ж догадался так данные складывать? Почему бы это всё не разделить на две сущности или перевести в объекты?

Comment: @doox911 это данные с yml файла, учусь/пробую. Я еще валенок во всем. Если подскажите, много благодарности Вам!

Comment: с `yml` -  не работал. Но с такой моделью данных работать не удобно. Вам надо всегда знать, что в первом элементе объект, а не строка. А это пораждает говнокод.